# Изменение размера формы пользователем

Tags: javascript

На сайте есть форма (по типу регистрации : введите меил, имя, зарегистрироваться и т.п.) в ней разные кнопки и инпуты. Нужно чтобы пользователь мог менять размеры самой формы , как бы растягивая ее. при наведении на края формы(углы) курсор меняет свой вид и позволяет растягивать форму. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать? Чистый JS

Comment: Зачем такое надо? Адаптив отменили?

Comment: Условие задания

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это возможно сделать без использования JS, для этого есть специальное свойство в CSS [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

Вот небольшой пример кода:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  /* Вот сюда и добавляем */
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
}

.form label {
  display: block margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <label for="name">Имя</label>
  <input id="name" placeholder="Введите имя">
  <br>
  <label for="surname">Фамилия</label>
  <input id="surname" placeholder="Введите фамилию">
  <h2 style="text-align: center">Какой-то текст посредине</h2>
</form>
```

Comment: Классно! Спасибо большое)

Comment: Принимаю благодарности!) 
PS: Если мой ответ является ответом на ваш вопрос, то можете поставить на него галочку :)

Comment: А как сделать чтобы скролла горизонтального не было, но при этом форма растягивалась?